# How to download and install gcc for AIX 7?

Tags: gcc, aix

I am new to installation work and AIX machine. I have gone through many sites and found it very difficult to follow/unrelated. I did `find / | grep gcc` and found only one gcc folder which cannot be executed. I tried installing gcc using the `rpm - libgcc8-8.3.0-5.aix7.2.ppc.rpm` and `libgcc-8-1.aix7.2.ppc.rpm`, still gcc not found. I will be thankful if I find some help on downloading and installing gcc in AIX machine. Please help.

```
# uname -v
7
# uname -a
AIX twa-aix72-01 2 7 00FB3B744C00
#
```

Comment: `find / | grep gcc` is a terrible way to find files. Just `find / -name '*gcc*'`. And did you check the `cc` command or the package manager in AIX?

Comment: when I give `# cc`,
`ksh: cc:  not found.` is the output. Could you tell why do we need to check package manager..?

Comment: It is `rpm -qa | grep gcc`; you can download gcc and its dependecies from here: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/aix-toolbox-open-source-software-downloads-alpha
Mind you, installing software should be done by your system admin, not yourself.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond Thank you lots for the guidance. I gave `# rpm -qa | grep gcc`
and the output is `libgcc8-8.3.0-5.ppc
libgcc-8-1.ppc`. Does this mean I have gcc installed already...?

Comment: You should install a package called `gcc8-8.3.0-5` (or the latest available version from gcc8) and every dependencies. Edit: if you are lucky, you might have yum installed on your AIX: try command `yum install gcc8`

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond Thank you so much.. I installed `gcc8` using `yum`. When I give `which gcc`, still gcc is not seen. My path is: `/usr/bin:/etc:/usr/sbin:/usr/ucb:/usr/bin/X11:/sbin:/usr/java8_64/jre/bin:/usr/java8_64/bin`. Could you help please?

Comment: Make sure to add `/opt/freeware/bin` into your path. (`/etc/environment` might be a way to do it permanently.)

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond Thank you lots.. `yum install gcc` and then `which gcc` worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used `yum install gcc` and then gave `which gcc`, I am able to see the gcc file path then. This worked. Yum downloads gcc package and installs I guess. For more details, please check the comments.